# Can I include an author URL as part of the affiliation block in an IEEE Conference Paper?

Tags: publications, conference, website, ieee, affiliation

I have an [OrcId](http://OrcId.Org).  When I publish papers, for example to IEEE conferences, I'd like to include my OrcId URL, in addition to my email in the author block in the document (in case my email changes and for collecting search results).  Is is allowed, for example with IEEE "related" events, to include an author URL, in addition to, an author email?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure. The IEEE [conference template](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/journals/ieee-conference/ieee-conference.pdf) even includes an example of an author who gives a web URL in the affiliation block:

> Michael Shell 
>   School of Electrical and Computer Engineering 
>   Georgia Institute of Technology 
>   Atlanta, Georgia 30332–0250 
>   Email: http://www.michaelshell.org/contact.html

The variety of examples in the template further make it clear that authors can choose whether or not to include details such as email, web URL, address, telephone number, and fax (!) number in the author affiliation block.